# SSH server is not disconnecting session when I shutdown the machine

Tags: arch-linux, sshd

I have a Arch Linux virtual machine, if I shutdown the machine while a ssh connection is alive. The SSH session would stuck (and the machine shuts down correctly)

So the server is not disconnecting the session before the SSH service gets stopped.

But on Ubuntu there's no such behavior, what problem could it be?

Comment: This might happen because network service gets shut down before ssh is, thus the session close does not reach the clients.